# Is there an app or another way to make an iPod Touch or iPhone emulate an older iPod Device?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, ipod

Specifically I am trying to play music from my iPod-Touch through my XBOX360, but I know there are other devices that [only work with the old iPod interfaces](http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/gamesandmedia/sharingmedia/ipod/useappleipod.aspx) and not the touch/iPhone.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an app, or some other method to make these devices emulate for the purposes of the USB connection more primitive iPods (Classic, Nano, Shuffle, etc.) so they can work with devices that only support the older interface.

Answer (score 4):

I'm thinking the solution here would take some major development. The app would have to stop the driver for the current iPod from being installed and instead present a driver for the older device you want to emulate. Most likely your current device running the app would probably have to be jailbroke. It would also take some testing and playing around to make sure the driver worked with the current device.

Before going as far as creating an app or something you could try playing around with different drivers on your own system while having your current device connected. Just go into Device Manager, find your device, right click and update driver. Then try to manually add the driver of a shuffle or something. See what works. Then decide if it is worthwhile to pursue.